# Exporting the graph results in Python or Tensorflow crash

Tags: google-colaboratory

coding I used to export the inference graph:

```
!python /content/export_inference_graph.py \
    --input_type=image_tensor \
    --pipeline_config_path=/content/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config \
    --output_directory={output_directory} \
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix={last_model_path}
```

Error I faced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/export_inference_graph.py", line 162, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/content/export_inference_graph.py", line 158, in main
    write_inference_graph=FLAGS.write_inference_graph)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/object_detection/models/research/object_detection/exporter.py", line 510, in export_inference_graph
    write_inference_graph=write_inference_graph)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/object_detection/models/research/object_detection/exporter.py", line 402, in _export_inference_graph
    tf.gfile.MakeDirs(output_directory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 438, in recursive_create_dir
    recursive_create_dir_v2(dirname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 453, in recursive_create_dir_v2
    pywrap_tensorflow.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.as_bytes(path))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: /content/drive/My; Operation not supported
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the path to My Drive inside double quotes. Otherwise the path to my drive will be accepted as separate paths since there is a space in between.